# What's the proper way to have envionrment variables inserted into my configuration file?

Tags: configuration, environment-variables, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq

Using Rails 5.0.1.  I have this in my config/initializers/sidekiq.rb file ...

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://#{ENV['REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR']}:#{ENV['REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT']}/12', namespace: "sidekiq_app_name_#{ENV['RAILS_ENV']}" }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: 'redis://#{ENV['REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR']}:#{ENV['REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT']}/12', namespace: "sidekiq_app_name_#{ENV['RAILS_ENV']}" }
end
```

Although I have the envionrment variables defined in my system, when I attempt to start my server, I get these errors ...

```
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load': /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/config/initializers/sidekiq.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting '}' (SyntaxError)
{ENV['REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR']}:#{ENV['REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP
                              ^
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/config/initializers/sidekiq.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_end
{ENV['REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT']}/12', namespace: "sidekiq_a
                              ^
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/config/initializers/sidekiq.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end-of-input
pp_name_#{ENV['RAILS_ENV']}" }
```

What's the proper way to insert environment variables into my configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gem figaro:

```
gem "figaro"
```

How to use it, in the [readme.txt](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) explain very easly:

```
config/application.yml

stripe_api_key: "sk_live_dSqzdUq80sw9GWmuoI0qJ9rL"



ENV["stripe_api_key"] # => "sk_live_dSqzdUq80sw9GWmuoI0qJ9rL"
ENV.key?("stripe_api_key") # => true
ENV["google_analytics_key"] # => nil
ENV.key?("google_analytics_key") # => false

Figaro.env.stripe_api_key # => "sk_live_dSqzdUq80sw9GWmuoI0qJ9rL"
Figaro.env.stripe_api_key? # => true
Figaro.env.google_analytics_key # => nil
Figaro.env.google_analytics_key? # => false
```

Comment: So that I understand properly, why is figaro different than setting my environment variables in my shell?  For instance, before kicking off the rails server, I can run "echo $REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR" and get back a value ("localhost").  Is the error I'm experiencing above a result of the fact that Rails is not picking up my global environment variables?

Comment: @Dave , that's endeed, figaro is just a tool to help you achieve that! but you can make it withtout it, I maybe thought if you look at the problem from another point of view you, you can achieve your goal

Comment: @Dave I hope you find my answer helpful

Comment: Hi, I definitely appreciate your offering a different point of view.  I will remove my shell environment variable definitions and give your solution a go to see if I get different results.